# How to create new library with (*.adsklib) extention in revit using revit api,

Tags: revit-api

I wish to save the revit material on particular location , how I do, In revit inside material browser it is possible to create new library and store the material in it , How this thing is possible through api .

"Create new library with .adsklib extension"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik, the Revit API offers no support whatsoever for interacting with `adsklib` files, cf. [Material Management and Libraries](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.5).